# Create a Pie Fact using ploygo show number of cars of different year, and different engine types

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, pie-chart

I want to take my data.csv file which has all the information I need and I want to create a pie chart using plotly.go to show the number of cars of different year, different engine types(horizontal direction of matrix), and different manufacturers(vertical direction of matrix)

```
import pandas as pd

##import plotly.graph_objects as pgo

import plotly.express as px


df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")


df = df.drop(df[df.feature_speed > "500000miles"].index)

# get the brands
make = df.groupby("make").sum()
engine = df.groupby("feature_engine")

# Plot the average price of different makes

fig = px.pie(make,values="year", names=make._stat_axis,title="Number of cars of Different Years")

fig.show()
```

This is what I have however does not give me the information I actually need:
Show the number of cars of different year
Different engine types
Different manufacturers

for the code I provided it gives me:
Make
Year which is not giving me the actual year for each make its giving me what I think is the sum of the entire years for that car.

Comment: pls, explain what doess it mean `this does not work` ?

Comment: @Bhargav Sorry about that I have edited the question which will allow people to understand it more

Comment: If you want a great answer, especially where data formatting plays a big part in answering, make your question reproducible. Since you used a pandas data frame, extract the data with `pd.DataFrame.to_dict` and copy the output exactly as it appears in your question (edit your question).